# Count how many objects from the list of objects are similar with aspect to an attribute value

Tags: python, list

This is my Sample Code:

```
import random
class Test:
    def __init__(self, pin, name):
        self.Pin = pin
        self.Name = name

objects = []
myPinList = [123, 323, 1234, 123, 12314, 1234, 1231, 5754, 5456, 4245, 6573, 5743, 567, 563]

objects.append(Test(random.choice(myPinList), "Jhon"))
objects.append(Test(random.choice(myPinList), "Nimra"))
objects.append(Test(random.choice(myPinList), "Thomas"))
objects.append(Test(random.choice(myPinList), "Treesa"))
objects.append(Test(random.choice(myPinList), "Newt"))
objects.append(Test(random.choice(myPinList), "Greny"))
```

Now i want to count the total numbers of objects which have the same value of PIN Attribute.

```
objects_having_same_Pin = ???
```

I searched a lot but coudn't find a pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`collections.Counter`** here:

```
cnts = Counter([i.Pin for i in objects])

# Counter({1231: 2, 1234: 1, 5456: 1, 5743: 1, 6573: 1})
```

Then if you want a total number just sum all of the values greater than one:

```
'{} users share a Pin'.format(sum([i for _, i in cnts.items() if i > 1]))

# '2 users share a Pin'
```

If you want to know *who* shares a pin, you  may use a **`collections.defaultdict`**:

```
dct = defaultdict(list)

for obj in objects:
    dct[obj.Pin].append(obj.Name)

# defaultdict(list,
#            {1231: ['Jhon', 'Thomas'],
#             1234: ['Nimra'],
#             5456: ['Treesa'],
#             5743: ['Newt'],
#             6573: ['Greny']})
```